# possible set inclusion

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, set-theory

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ and $U(S) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ the normalized version of $S$ defined by $$U(S) = \left\{\frac{x}{||x||_2} | x \in S-{0} \right\}.$$ Let $A: S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear map such that for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^+$:  $$a||x||_2 \le ||Ax||_2 \le b||x||_2\qquad \forall x \in S.$$

I am suspecting that $A(U(S))\subseteq U(A(S)).$ In other words the normalized version of the image of $S$ under $A$ contains the image of the normalized version of $S$ under $A$. I am actually working on a problem that would be much easier to solve if this claim is true. Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Counterexample: $A(x)=2x,S=\Bbb R^N.$

Comment: yeah that's true. But is it possible to show that $A(U(S)) $ is contained in some $\epsilon-neighborhood$ of $U(A(S)).$?

Comment: Is $S$ a linear subspace? (else, I don't understand how $A$ can be defined only on $S$ and linear). Is $\Bbb R^n$ a misprint for $\Bbb R^N?$ Is your $\forall x\in\Bbb R^N$ a misprint for $\forall x\in S?$ (else, it is meaningless if $A$ is defined only on $S$). Isn't the existence of $a\in\Bbb R^+$ (i.e. $a>0?$) equivalent to: $A$ is injective? (and the existence of $b$ always true?) What were your efforts to prove or disprove your claim?

Comment: $A(U(S))$ is bounded, hence contained in an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $U(A(S)),$ and even in an  $\epsilon$-neighborhood of an arbitrary single point of $U(A(S)),$